# Оставить в массиве лишь элементы которые больше всего дублируются

Tags: php, массивы

На входе у нас есть некий массив. Если в нем ни один элемент не дублируется например:

```
$array = [1,2,3];
```

тогда ничего с ним не делаем и пропускаем его дальше

Если в нем хотя бы один элемент дублируется например:

```
$array = [1,1,2,3,3];
```

тогда оставляем только по одному разу те элементы, которые дублируются

Пока что нашёл такое решение:

```
$array = [1,1,2,3,3];
$duplicate = false;
foreach(array_count_values($array) as $item)
{
    if($item > 1)
    {
        $duplicate = true;
    }
}
if($duplicate == true)
{
    $array = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array,array_unique($array)));
}
print_r($array); // 1,3
```

Но на входе может быть массив, в котором какие то элементы дублируются например по два раза, а другие например по три раза и нужно оставить лишь те, которые дублируются больше всего раз. Причем элементов-дублей может быть любое количество например:

```
$array = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4];
```

соответственно нужно получить

```
[2,4]
```

Как можно решить задачу?

И может наличие дублей можно проверять как то проще вместо моего `if($duplicate == true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4];
$arr = array_count_values($arr);
asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$max = end($arr);
$result = array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($max) {return $v === $max; });
$result = array_keys($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a27104f6a84059fe217e383eacb52df9fee544e

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию *(без пары лишних функций)*:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4];

$arr = array_count_values($arr);
$max = max($arr);
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k)use($max, &$result){
    $v !== $max ?: $result[] = $k;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Считаем количество дублей
2. Сортируем и находим максимум
3. Формируем итоговый массив

```php
function save_dups($AArray) {
  // Считаем количество дублей
  $dups = array_count_values($AArray);

  // Сортируем и находим максимум
  arsort($dups);
  $maxCnt = reset($dups);

  // Формируем итоговый массив
  $res = [];
  foreach ($dups as $key => $val) {
    if ($val !== $maxCnt)
      break;
    $res[] = $key;
  }
  return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]; // исходный массив
$count_array = array_count_values($array); // количество вхождений
$result_array = []; // итоговый массив
$max_count = 0; // максимальное количество вхождений

foreach ($count_array as $key => $value) {
     if ($value >= $max_count) {

         if ($value > $max_count) {
             $max_count = $value;
             $result_array = [];
         }

         $result_array[] = $key;
     }
}
```

как вариант, код, кончено, можно оптимизировать